# What is math symbol?

Tags: c#, lucene

I'm working with lucene framework, in the norm(t,d) formula, I see this symbol and I don't know what is it. please exlain it for me, thank you!

[image: symbol image]

Answer (score 1):

It is the capital Greek letter Pi and it is used as the product operator for a product of a sequence (like capital Sigma for sums).

In this case, the product is calculated over the field f in d named as t.

See [Wikipedia: Capital Pi notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation)

Answer (score 0):

That is `Pi` letter in `capital` you can find it here [Pi_(letter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_(letter))